# update attribute that is html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rel

I have a anchor `<a></a>` with an attribute `rel`. in the rel value there is html, such as `<a rel="html=<div>This is a test</div>`. I want to update html inside of rel value, I can update the actual change on the page but if i go to the next slide and come back, its back to what it was before because the rel value is not updated. I am not sure how to go about doing this. Any suggestions, I am using [Clearbox](http://www.clearbox.hu/index_en.html) by the way.

Example(I know the html is incorrect on here, but it is correct on my page. I just need to know how to update it through jquery or any other way)

```
<a rel="html=<div class="testclass"> This is a test</div></a>
```

a piece of the html element (not the a) Needs to be changed to

```
<a rel="html=<div class="testclass"> No more testing </div></a>
```

Comment: `rel` is not a place to put arbitrary data. In fact, you shouldn't be storing HTML markup within HTML attributes.

Comment: That's not even valid HTML. Your first `a` tag never gets closed. Should at least be `<a rel="html=<div class=\"testclass\"> This is a test</div>"></a>
`.

Comment: If you want to put HTML in your rel, which you shouldn't do, at least escape your quotes, and close the rel attribute like so `<a rel="html=<div class=\"testclass\"> This is a test</div>">link</a>`

Comment: I did, i just wrote that for an example. Just image that the quotes are not there like that, just know that the html is all correct, but how do I update it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (But SHOULDN'T) do that with

```
this.rel = 'html=<div>But you shouldnt do that</div>';
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dEhkK/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to avoid the use of double quotes inside another double quotes, if you are using double quotes to wrap a string use single quotes inside that string and vice versa.

See this --> http://jsfiddle.net/Galled/rXKCL/14/